# CSS how to style only an element in the first instance it appears on a page

Tags: css, css-selectors

Suppose I have to similar articles:

```
<article>
  <hr>
   <p> This is line 1</p>
   <p> This is line 2</p>
</article>

<article>
<hr>
  <p> This is line 1</p>
  <p> This is line 2</p>
</article>
```

But I only want styling to affect the FIRST p tag of the very first article and not the first p tag of both articles. I've tried the first child and the first-of-type but in those cases it affects the first p of both articles. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The selector for that would be `article:first-child p:first-child { ... }` (i.e. first-child p inside first-child article)

You might want to use `:first-of-type` instead of `:first-child`, especially for `article` if there is other content before the first article.

Answer (score 0):

use first-child pseudo element to article and to p tag

```
article:first-child p:first-child{
  //your style
}
```